# SWIFT 2: Class ViewController has no initializers - Using GOOGLE's Admob

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob, viewcontroller

I was following a Youtube tutorial to learn how to use Google's AdMob with Swift on XCode: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJi-vQ9e-HI

I got an error saying that my class "ViewController" has no identifiers.

It had worked just fine for the guy on Youtube, we put in the same frameworks, imported the same frameworks, wrote the same code. The only difference I believe is that he was developing for iOS 9.1 while I was doing it for 9.3.

The picture linked below has my code for the ViewController.swift file and I do not know what is wrong with it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

[ViewController.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4stT.png)

Comment: try with `var banner : GADBannerView!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't initialize the banner before loading the view, you have to make sure it exists. So this should fix it:

```
var adBanner: GADBannerView!
```